# Как проставить ключи в массиве?

Tags: php

Всем привет ! Нужна помощь с ключами в массиве, сейчас есть такой вариант:

```
$c=0;
                foreach ($n as $keys => $values) {
                    $c++;
                        if ($values["PROPERTY_DAYTIME_VALUE"] == 1366 && $values["PROPERTY_TYPE_VALUE"] == 1375) {
                    $arItem[0]["SUBCATEGORY"][0]["PRODUCTS"][$c]["ID"] = $values["ID"];
                    $arItem[0]["SUBCATEGORY"][0]["PRODUCTS"][$c]["NAME"] = $values["NAME"];
                    $arItem[0]["SUBCATEGORY"][0]["PRODUCTS"][$c]["PREVIEW_PICTURE"] = $values["DETAIL_PICTURE"];
                    $arItem[0]["SUBCATEGORY"][0]["PRODUCTS"][$c]["PREVIEW_TEXT"] = $values["DETAIL_TEXT"];
                    $arItem[0]["SUBCATEGORY"][0]["PRODUCTS"][$c]["PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE"] = $values["DETAIL_TEXT_TYPE"];
                    $arItem[0]["SUBCATEGORY"][0]["PRODUCTS"][$c]["IMAGE_URL"] = $values["IMAGE_URL"];
                        }
}
```

Распечатаный выглядит вот так:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 1366
            [NAME] => Завтрак
            [UF_TIME] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10:00
                )

            [SUBCATEGORY] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [ID] => 1782
                            [NAME] => Закуски острые
                            [UF_MAX_CHOOSEN_BLUD] => 1
                            [PRODUCTS] => Array
                                (
                                    [172] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 2002
                                            [NAME] => test1
                                            [PREVIEW_PICTURE] => 417
                                            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => 
                                            [PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE] => text
                                            [IMAGE_URL] => http://emcq.zapusq.ru/upload/iblock/659/food-12.png
                                        )

                                    [178] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ID] => 2017
                                            [NAME] => test14
                                            [PREVIEW_PICTURE] => 
                                            [PREVIEW_TEXT] => 
                                            [PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE] => text
                                            [IMAGE_URL] => http://emcq.zapusq.ru
                                        )

                                )

                        )
...
```

Нужно сделать так, что бы в массиве PRODUCTS ключи, каждый раз начинались с 0 и шли дальше по порядку.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$arr = Array(
    Array("ID" => 1366,
        "NAME" => "Завтрак",
        "UF_TIME" => Array("10:00"),
        "SUBCATEGORY" => Array(
                Array(
                        "ID" => 1782,
                        "NAME" => "Закуски острые",
                        "UF_MAX_CHOOSEN_BLUD" => 1,
                        "PRODUCTS" => Array(
                                "172" => Array(
                                        "ID" => 2002,
                                        "NAME" => "test1",
                                        "PREVIEW_PICTURE" => 417,
                                        "PREVIEW_TEXT" => '',
                                        "PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE" => "text",
                                        "IMAGE_URL" => "http://emcq.zapusq.ru/upload/iblock/659/food-12.png"),
                                "178" => Array(
                                        "ID" => 2017,
                                        "NAME" => "test14",
                                        "PREVIEW_PICTURE" => "",
                                        "PREVIEW_TEXT" => "",
                                        "PREVIEW_TEXT_TYPE" => "text",
                                        "IMAGE_URL" => "http://emcq.zapusq.ru")
                        )

                )
        )
    )
);


$arr[0]['SUBCATEGORY'][0]['PRODUCTS'] = array_values($arr[0]['SUBCATEGORY'][0]['PRODUCTS']);
print_r($arr[0]['SUBCATEGORY'][0]['PRODUCTS']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Решено. Если кому интересно:

```
$arItem[0]["SUBCATEGORY"][0]["PRODUCTS"][]=[
    "ID"=>$values["ID"],
    ...
];
```